# migrate google apps script project to new domain

Tags: google-apps-script, cross-domain

I've been developing a series of Google App Script projects for a Google Apps for Business client, which are designed to be embedded into their sites pages.

To date, the development and demonstration has been done in my domain (partly because the client would not move their domain to Google unless I could make this bespoke web app work for them).

Now we are at the point we want to transition all of this into their domain.

I guess I could just copy and paste all the files, recreating the projects as I go.

But is there some more elegant way of managing this, eg, to copy the existing projects to the new domain on a project basis?

There's no need to maintain a linkage between the projects in the old domain and the new one, except as a nice to have (so I could keep developing and testing in my domain)

Answer (score 1):

Would just have the client make a copy of your files from their new domain then add you back as an editor.  Don't see any reason to copy and paste anything.  Since editors can now access the dev link on other's scripts, that may be a reason to not need a library setup.  You would just be testing and making changes from their file's script editor from now on.

The owner also has to be the 1st to initially deploy the web app.  Have noticed that when you're an deploying subsequent updates as an editor, your domain name still appears in the permissions drop-down on who can access but it does get implemented as theirs.

Comment: What ended up working for me was to just take the link where my current app is deployed and then put that into the new project (Doh).

Comment: A new project of yours or the clients?  I'm not following.

Comment: the new project is mine.  The original app script was shared with me via google Drive, but I have full permissions to modify, etc.  So, if I "deploy as web app" in the App Script, it gives me a url where the app is deployed.  Then in my project, I can include  an App Script and paste in the link and then the app-script app shows up in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your projects into libraries so you don't have two separate instances of the script. Then you could create one MasterScript on their domain that calls the various project scripts: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries